# Outlook 2013 to outlook.com mail or vice versa

Tags: outlook.com

Not sure if I'm in the right space, but is there ANY way that I can get my Outlook 2013 emails from the collection of private domains I have to sync up to 2013?

**OR alternatively**

Do I need to sign all my addresses up to outlook.com? If so, can I or how do I UPLOAD all my existing mails and folders to outlook.com from 2013?

I am an 0365 user, FYI.

Comment: Are you wanting to simply SEE emails from multiple accounts in one place, or actually consolidate those emails into a single account?

Answer (score 1):

Large scale syncing of email is not really a good idea. It is possible but not recommended.

If you simply want to move to a different mail domain, the easiest way is to use Outlook client. Add all of the accounts to Outlook and you can simply copy and paste emails, contacts, calendar entries, etc. That is also the best answer to your second question & yes, you need to copy your addresses over.

You could also look at 3rd-party synch tools but having used most of them over the years, I don't really recommend them. You will end up with duplicates that then need manually resolving.

You imply but don't say that your private domains are also on Exchange. If this is not the case, there might be other options for copying but we would need to know what mail systems the domains use. I'm not aware of any sync tools for Office 365 email/contacts/etc. Though you may find it easy to do via another platform - typically your mobile.

Comment: Have you checked out the new facilities Microsoft are making available for bulk email transfer? These may only be available to enterprise customers - not sure - but worth checking out.